# How to connect DotsIndicator to PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created my own indicator but I can't connect it to the page view. When I turn pages, my dot just stays where it is, meaning it doesn't switch when I go to another screen. Could you please add what is missing to my code or tell me where my mistake is?

It is my code:

```
class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
      //controller dlya dot
      // ignore: prefer_final_fields
      PageController _controller = PageController();
      bool onLastPage = false;


   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return  Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
//page view
      children:  [
          PageView(
            controller: _controller,
            onPageChanged: (index){
                setState(() {
                  onLastPage = (index == 2);
                });
            },
        children: const  [
         IntroPage1(),
         IntroPage2(),
         IntroPage3(),
        ],
      ),

      // dot indekator
    
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 672, left: 95, right: 16),
      // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
      child: Container(
        child: DotsIndicator(
          dotsCount: 3,
          reversed: false,
        
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          decorator: DotsDecorator(
            spacing: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24),
            size: const  Size(35.0,16.0),
            color: Colors.white,
            shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
            ) ,
            
            
            activeSize: const Size(65.0, 16.0),
            activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 179, 71),
            activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
            )
          ),
         ), 
       ),
     ), 
   ],
 ),  


);


 }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to pass the `index` from your pageview to the `position` property on DotsIndicator, most likely using your page's state.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to be notified when the _controller page changes:
for example:

```
    double? actualPage = 0;
_controller .addListener(() {
   if(actualPage != _controller .page){
     actualPage = _controller .page;
     changeDotsIndicator(actualPage);
   }
 });
```

After this you need to tell "DotsDecorator()" that the page is changed.
You could do this by giving it a key "keyDotsIndicator" and calling a method inside the DotsDecorator class to make the real work on your dots.

```
GlobalKey<DotsDecoratorState> keyDotsIndicator = GlobalKey();


DotsDecorator(
    key: keyDotsIndicator,
    ...
    ...
)

void changeDotsIndicator(double page){
    keyDotsIndicator.currentState!.myMethodToEditDotsIndicators(page)
}
```

Important thing, DotsDecorator has to be a statefull widget